# How to add unsigned digital signature block to existing file with code

Tags: java, c#, sharepoint, pdf-generation, digital-signature

I'm looking for a way to programatically add unsigned digital signature blocks to existing microsoft and pdf documents. We are generating these documents from Sql Server Reporting Services, and want to send these documents to Sharepoint for digital signature workflows.

I know creating unsigned digital signature blocks is possible through Microsoft Infopath, but it does not have some of the bells and whistles we need.

Ideally we'd like to use C# or Java, but are open to other implementations.

Comment: Which pdf library do you plan to use?

Comment: No plans, we can use whichever library that gives us the capability we need :)

Comment: In that case your question is in danger of being considered off topic as it implicitly asks for a library recommendation, and requests for library recommendations are considered OT here. That been said, you should at least indicate which software licenses are ok for you as this may reduce applicable libraries considerably.

Comment: Not asking for a recommendation, as I dont know which libraries are CAPABLE of doing this. My hour plus research hasn&#39;t given me any leads, I may not be searching with the correct terms. We'd prefer free/open source if possible

Comment: Well, I know that itext (both for java and for c#) can create empty signature fields, pdfbox (predominantly java but there also are .Net ports) should also be able to do it. But I would actually expect *any general purpose pdf library* to have that feature...